# IE11 error when JSON.stringify the result of a lodash merged object

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer, merge, lodash

OS Windows 8.1 |
IE11 - v11.0.9 |
lodash - v4.17.4

Given I use lodash merge to merge one object into another.
Where the object to be merged has a number, (integer or string), key.
And the result is fed to JSON.stringify.
Then I should see the two objects merged in the resulting string.

```
const a = {
  '1': 1
};
const b = {
  key: {
    '2': 2
  }
};
_.merge(a, b);
console.log(JSON.stringify(a)); //-> {"1":1,"key":{}}
```

Expect:
{"1":1,"key":{"2": 2}}

Actual:
{"1":1,"key":{}}

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0a7euzas/10/

Interestingly, if I add a property with an alpha character, or a appended/prepended alpha character to the '2' property of the key object, the output string is correct.

Answer (score 2):

IE11 on Windows 8.1 seems to have a bug with `JSON.stringify` at any depth, where if an object has only numeric keys under UINT32_MAX - 1, it would serialize it to an empty object.

This has been the only other occurrence I've seen for this. The poor man's solution, as you've noticed, is to add an alphanumeric key, and simply ignore it at the deserialization on the way back.

[Example from our codebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufXMp.png)